# Уточнение с константами

Tags: c++, ассемблер

```
void fun()    
{
    int i = 5;
}
```

В данном случае, 5 - это константа?

Как это будет выглядеть на asm?

Comment: Как *что* будет выглядеть? У вашего кода нет никакого наблюдаемого поведения. Любой компилятор просто выкинет его нафиг целиком.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5 - это литерал.

Ну, например,

```
    ;; Вход в функцию
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx

    ;; Инициализация переменной в стеке
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 5
```

А то и без этого - оптимизатор может разместить значение в регистре, например, или использовать непосредственно значение 5.

О строке - будет что-то типа

```
msg DB  'is const', 00H

f PROC
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 8

mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 5
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], OFFSET msg

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret 0
f ENDP
```

Comment: `mov DWORD PTR [ebp - 4], 5`

Comment: Без вопросов...

Comment: @Harry, а если char* str = "is const?"?

Comment: @akula, сама строка скорее всего будет в области глобальных данных находиться, а в переменной просто ее адрес будет. Вообще и в том и в другом случае переменной на стеке может не быть, смотря как компилятор оптимизирует код.

Comment: О строке - см. дополненный ответ. Опять же, оптимизатор может сделать самые разные вещи и с указателем...